# Vim not highlighting syntax for bash scripts (msysgit version)

Tags: bash, vim, msysgit, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using the bash and vim that come with msysgit. I've added the `.vimrc` file to my home folder and most of the commands there are executing. But `syntax on` is not.

This is the contents of my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set cul
hi CursorLine cterm=none ctermbg=darkgray ctermfg=white
syntax on
```

The current line and highlighting is now working, but the `syntax on` is failing. Msysgit installs it's own vim and in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\share\vim\vim73\syntax` folder, it does not contain a bash.vim or sh.vim file. Other files are in there like conf.vim, gitcommit.vim and gitrebase.vim - even c.vim.

I'm guessing this is why there is no highlighting. Given that I can't touch that folder (don't ask), how can I change my .vimrc file to load up a bash.vim file - and what's a good place to get one?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does ":set syn=sh" turn the highlighting on?

Comment: ok, can you see ANY syntax highlighting? On a C file (since it seems to have c.vim)? With or without forcing with ":set syn=c" ":syn on"

Comment: can try on superuser, the user there should have the better answer

Comment: I see syntax hilighting when I commit or rebase interactively. Seems that the files in the directory I mention are doing their job.

Comment: there exists a c.vim file in there and sure enough, when I open a .c file, it's highlighted.

Comment: ugh, you would still need to see the function that decides which file to load for syntax highlighting. If you need a command to enable highlighting, you can always source the syntax file with ":so /path/to/bash.vim", but you probably don't want that. In general, when you type ":syn on", vim executes ":runtime! syntax.vim", which typically loads "synload.vim", which decides on which actual syntax file to load. You can look at these files, and see what you can salvage and put into your .vimrc

Comment: since I now saw your other comment -- try changing runtimepath in your .vimrc to include path to syntax files from another vim distro that has syntax for your shell files. It may still not work, as there is a process that determines which syntax file to load based on file type, and it's not just by extension, and msysgit distro may not have code that recognizes shell files.

Comment: could I not add a `source $HOME/vimfiles/plugins/sh.vim` in my .vimrc file? I would rename bash-support.vim to sh.vim. I came across something that said the name of the plugin vim file has to match the extension.

Comment: stack overflow isn't there yet for anything out of the ordinary. I'm going to try IRC and post back here.

Comment: If you source 'sh.vim', it will unconditionally set shell syntax for all of your files.

Comment: hmm. ok.. so how do I source it for only .sh files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. search and download [`sh.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1632) via google or anything else you prefer to.
2. move sh.vim to `$HOME/vimfiles/syntax/` directory, then when you open a shell script it'll take effect for that.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_44.html#44.11

Comment: For the record it's `$HOME/vimfiles/syntax/`, and syntax files can be found [here](http://www.vim.org/vimscriptlinks.php) or directly [sh.vim](http://drchip.0sites.net/astronaut/vim/syntax/sh.vim.gz).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried enabling the filetype plugin?

```
:filetype plugin on
```

Then, if your script syntax still doesn't colorize properly, try manual override:

```
:set ft=sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with msysgit, but to answer your final question:

> how can I change my .vimrc file to load up a bash.vim file

you should be able to add:

```
if filereadable(expand("$HOME/some/path/bash.vim"))
    execute "source " . "$HOME/some/path/bash.vim"
endif
```

This might be useful if you have a reachable installed copy and don't wish to maintain your own copy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting everything in ~/.vim/view helped. I had `mkview` under `autocmd`, so when I did not shut down vim and bash properly, I think some files got corrupted. I found this problem by moving the files that were giving me trouble in another directory and finding out that vim had no problem showing their syntax properly.